# How to get the last created file, among a list of file names

Tags: shell, batch-file, makefile, nmake

## Problem

I have this `Makefile` to be run by the Windows NMAKE tool:

```
push:
    cd dist
    "C:\Program Files\Rhino 7\System\Yak.exe" push myapp-*.yak
```

The above statement throws a fatal error. Since the `Yak.exe` tool expects a full path/name of the file.

## Question

There is a `dist` subfolder containing files like:

- `myapp-1.2.0-rh7_13-win.yak`
- `myapp-1.3.0-rh7_13-win.yak`
- `myapp-1.4.0-rh7_13-win.yak`
- ...

How can I programmatically get the full name of the last created file? I'm looking for a *simple* Windows batch script that I can implement inside my `Makefile`, ideally.

### Options

I'm playing around with some options. But I cannot figure out how to actually implement them. At least two approaches can determine the last created file:

1. The largest version numbers of `L`, `M` and `N` inside this pattern: `myapp-L.M.N-*-win.yak`
2. The timestamp.
3. ...?

## UPDATE

With the help of @Stephan I implemented this approach.

```
push:
    cd dist
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /od /a-d myapp-*-win.yak') do set LAST=%%i
    "C:\Program Files\Rhino 7\System\Yak.exe" push "%LAST%"
```

I'm on the right track. But it has a problem. The `%LAST%` variable is not properly passed from the `for` loop to the `push` statement. I'm not sure how to pass the variable properly.

Also, using `do set "LAST=%%i"` has the same problem as `do set LAST=%%i`

Comment: `dir /on` sorts the files by name ` dir /o-n` reverses the sort order. Put a `for /f` loop around to capture the first one: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n myapp*') do if not defined latest set "latest=%%a"`. For a timestamp approach use `dir /o-d`, maybe with the `/tc` option (see `dir /?`)

Comment: @Stephan I implemented an approach inspired by your help. I'm on the right track. But looks like there is something wrong with passing the variable from the loop to the next statement of the Makefile. I updated my post.

Comment: You mentioned "expects a full path/name". Your `for` loop gets the name and extension only. See `for /?` ("modifiers" section) how to retrieve the full path (`%%~fi`). For troubleshooting, run with `echo on` to see exactly how your code is parsed (with expanded variables)

Comment: @Stephan Sorry. I made a mistake. Looks like it works by just the full name. Looks like using a combination of `cd` to change the directory and then getting the full name is good enough.

Comment: Great. Consider adding your working solution as an answer and accept it (after cooldown) to mark the question as "answered" and help others, who might have a similar issue.

Comment: @Stephan Right. I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach finally worked:

```
push:
    cd dist
    echo off > temp.bat
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /od /a-d myapp-*-win.yak') do echo "C:\Program Files\Rhino 7\System\Yak.exe" push "%%i" > temp.bat
    call temp.bat
    del temp.bat
```

A temporary batch file `temp.bat` is created. For each `myapp-*-win.yak` file, a statement is written to `temp.bat`, overwriting the previous statement. Therefore, after the loop, `temp.bat` contains the statement for the latest file.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach. However, it works so far.

Comment: creating temporary files is suboptimal (several times accessing the filesystem makes it slow (in terms of computer time - you might not notice a difference) and is usually only used when there really is no alternative. Your original attempt to set a variable should work fine (use recommended syntax to avoid stray spaces: `set "LAST=%%i"`  - note the position of the quotes). What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Stephan Right. When I set the variable, the variable `LAST` is not set properly. It isn't accessible by the next line of the Makefile statement. The Makefile statement becomes something like this: `"C:\Program Files\Rhino 7\System\Yak.exe" push "%LAST%"`

Comment: Is your code in a code block? Then you fell into the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). does `echo "%last%"` (or `echo "!last!"` with delayed expansion enabled) show the correct string?

Comment: forget about delayed expansion - it that were the issue, also your approach with the temp file wouldn't work.

Comment: @Stephan Right. I also tried a combination of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `"!LAST!"` and `endlocal` but they didn't work. Then I moved on to the temp file that worked fine :)